# Powershell failure to connect to SQL Server

Tags: powershell

I am trying to send some basic data to a SQL Server hosted on our company website. My web dev checked on the Server side and the connection is allowed but I keep getting this response from PowerShell:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s):
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I have verified the credentials are all correct. MySQL Workbench logged into the SQL server without issues.

This is my connection code. The connection values are edited for obvious security reasons.

```
function upload_SQL () {
    $SQLServer = "server.com"
    $SQLDBName = "DB_Name"
    $uid ="User_Name"
    $pwd = "Pass"

    Write-Host "Attempting to connect to $SQLServer"
    $ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLServer; Database=$SQLDBName; Integrated Security=True; User ID=$uid; Password=$pwd;"
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ConnectionString)
    $conn.Open()
    $SqlQuery = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $SqlQuery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO total2_gariondata.Test () VALUES ('
            $DTinfo,
            $ClientCode,
            $CompCode,
            $CPUstat, 
            $MEMstat, 
            $DSKstat,
            $TimePeriods,
            $CritErr1,
            $WarnErr1,
            $SpaceUsed
        ');"
    $SqlQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $conn.Close()
}
```

Comment: Where is the code running? On your desktop or on another server?

Comment: Code is running on my work PC

Comment: If the code is running on the same machine as MySQL Workbench and under the same user credentials as MySQL Workbench but the code does not connect and workbench does then All I can think of is a bad connection string or else the Workbench and powershell are using different ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` is only for MS SQL-Server and not compatible with MySQL-Server.

Change it to `New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection`.

To make it work, you need at least `MySQL.Data.dll` from the MySQL  .NET Connector (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html)
i placed the dll in the same Folder where the Sript is running.

**Update**:

You need to import the dll before using it.
This small Script works for me, if the dll is in the same folder where the script is:

```
Add-Type -Path "$(Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)\MySQL.Data.dll"

$SQLServer = "server.com"
$SQLDBName = "DB_Name"
$uid       = "User_Name"
$pwd       = "Pass"


$Command             = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$conn                = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=$SQLServer;user id=$uid;password=$pwd;database=$SQLDBName")
$Command.CommandText = "Your Update / Insert Command"
$Command.Connection  = $conn

$Command.Connection.Open()
[int]$i = $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$Command.Connection.Close()
```

$i is holding the number of affected Rows

Comment: I forgot to say, that the dll must be importet:

`Add-Type -Path "$(Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)\MySQL.Data.dll"`

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested. I had to make the `Add-Type` command a direct path as `$Split-Path` caused errors. I am now getting this error:
> verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Comment: Thanks. That part is now resolved, but there is an access denied error coming mySQL. Passwords and usernames are all correct. I am testing on a local machine. Right now I am looking through all the SQL info to find a way to allow this communication